# Hidden table occupying space from the 2nd page of report viewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, rdlc, report-viewer2010

I have 5 tables next to each other(horizontally) in a report . If there are no rows in the table then the table should hide, and the tables right to it should occupy its space. This is happening in the first page of the report viewer, (I have set the visibility based on a expression). But from the 2nd page there is empty white space in place of the hidden table. Please help

Comment: Try putting the tables each in a cell in a parent table, and hide/show the static column in the Column Groups view of the parent table.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have hidden the tables based on the exp Count()>0 then hide, and it works perfectly in the first page of the pdf, but when there is more data and the table expands to the 2nd page of pdf, thats when there is empty space in the place of hidden table. I could use your solution but I have totally 10 tables , I could not put them side to side due to width issues, I have 5 tables  on the top and 5 tables  at the bottom, Also there is another issue, if one of the tables in the top 5 tables is hidden, then I want the 6th table to go to the top , which is not happening